# Как управлять прокруткой страницы при использовании хэша и

Tags: html, javascript

Заголовок плохо отражает суть вопроса.
У меня на странице поставлено множество якорей `<a name="c1...с50"></a>` и переход происходит по ссылке с хэшем #c1. Так вот, необходимо чтобы видимая область окна прокручивалась не к самому якорю, а на позицию на 50 пикселей выше якоря.

UPD
Решил так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Прокрутка к закладке
    if(window.location.hash) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()-50;
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollTop}, 'fast');
        }, 50);
    }
})
```

То есть, просто ждем 50 миллисекунд после загрузки и откручиваем окно на 50 пикселей наверх...

Comment: Вот тоже ищу, но никак не могу найти, прошу автора, если найдет отписаться) Я тоже отпишусь тут, если найду решение)

Comment: Свое решение я добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать вот этот вариант:

```
function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
    time = typeof(time) != 'undefined' ? time : 1000;
    verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
    element = $(selector);
    offset = element.offset();
    offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, time);
}
```

Однако придётся вешать обработчик на каждую ссылку, примерно такого вида:

```
$('a.jump-to-content').click(function () {
    scrollToElement('#c1',500, -50); // #c1 - наш элемент, 500 - время анимации,       -50 это 50px до нашего элемента
});
```

Взято из [этой статьи](http://www.dconnell.co.uk/blog/index.php/2012/03/12/scroll-to-any-element-using-jquery/).

Comment: В моем случае навигация не внутри одного документа, а между разными страницами. Так что, мне подходит по document.ready